# Check one row value of a column and apply that particular value to all the rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table

| Key | Seq | True |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11001 | 1 | Yes |
| 11001 | 2 | No |
| 11001 | 3 | No |
| 12002 | 1 | No |
| 12002 | 2 | No |
| 12002 | 3 | No |
| 14002 | 1 | Yes |
| 14002 | 2 | No |
| 14002 | 3 | No |
| 14002 | 4 | No |

The output should be:

| Key | Seq | True |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11001 | 1 | Yes |
| 11001 | 2 | Yes |
| 11001 | 3 | Yes |
| 12002 | 1 | No |
| 12002 | 2 | No |
| 12002 | 3 | No |
| 14002 | 1 | Yes |
| 14002 | 2 | Yes |
| 14002 | 3 | Yes |
| 14002 | 4 | Yes |

Logic: If a "Key" has "Yes" in "True" then apply "Yes" in "True" column to all the rows having same "Key" value.

Comment: Use [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html). There are several questions on this forum, but unfortunately there is no easy way to find a suitable duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `True` if match at least one value with `Yes` and for matched keys check original column `Key` for final mask by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), then set column in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['True'] = np.where(df['Key'].isin(df.loc[df['True'].eq('Yes'), 'Key']), 'Yes', 'No')
#alternatives
#df.loc[df['Key'].isin(df.loc[df['True'].eq('Yes'), 'Key']), 'True'] = 'Yes'

#df.loc[df['True'].eq('Yes').groupby(df['Key']).transform('any'), 'True'] = 'Yes'
print (df)
     Key  Seq True
0  11001    1  Yes
1  11001    2  Yes
2  11001    3  Yes
3  12002    1   No
4  12002    2   No
5  12002    3   No
6  14002    1  Yes
7  14002    2  Yes
8  14002    3  Yes
9  14002    4  Yes
```

Or if there are only `Yes/No` values is possible get maximal value per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['True'] = df.groupby('Key')['True'].transform('max')
```